# How to find the neighbors of a graph effiiciently

Tags: algorithm, search, graph, graph-algorithm, path-finding

I have a program that create graphs as shown below

[image: Structure of the created graph]

The algorithm starts at the green color node and traverses the graph. Assume that a node (Linked list type node with 4 references Left, Right, Up and Down) has been added to the graph depicted by the red dot in the image. Inorder to integrate the newly created node with it neighbors I need to find the four objects and link it so the graph connectivity will be preserved.

Following is what I need to clarify

1. Assume that all yellow colored nodes are null and I do not keep a another data structure to map nodes what is the most efficient way to find the existence of the neighbors of the newly created node. I know the basic graph search algorithms like DFS, BFS etc and shortest path algorithms but I do not think any of these are efficient enough because the graph can have about 10000 nodes and doing graph search algorithms (starting from the green node) to find the neighbors when a new node is added seems computationally expensive to me.
2. If the graph search is not avoidable what is the best alternative structure. I thought of a large multi-dimensional array. However, this has memory wastage and also has the issue of not having negative indexes. Since the graph in the image can grow in any directions. My solution to this is to write a separate class that consists of a array based data structure to portray negative indexes. However, before taking this option I would like to know if I could still solve the problem without resolving to a new structure and save a lot of rework.

Thank you for any feedback and reading this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand you correctly. Do you want to

- Check that there is a path from (0,0) to (x1,y1)

or

- Check if any of the neighbors of (x1,y1) are in the graph? (even if there is no path from (0,0) to any of this neighbors).

I assume that you are looking for a path (otherwise you won't use a linked-list), which implies that you can't store points which have no path to (0,0).

Also, you mentioned that you don't want to use any other data structure beside / instead of your 2D linked-list.

You can't avoid full graph search. BFS and DFS are the classic algorithms. I don't think that you care about the shortest path - any path would do.

Another approaches you may consider is A* (simple explanation [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pathfinding)) or one of its variants (look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%2a_search_algorithm#Variants_of_A.2A)).

An alternative data structure would be a set of nodes (each node is a pair < x,y > of course). You can easily run 4 checks to see if any of its neighbors are already in the set. It would take O(n) space and O(*logn*) time for both check and add. If your programming language does not support pairs as nodes of a set, you can use a single integer (x*(Ymax+1) + Y) instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a spatial index like a quad tree or a r-tree.

Answer (score 0):

Your data structure can be made to work, but probably not efficiently.  And it will be a lot of work.

With your current data structure you can use an A* search (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm for a basic description) to find a path to the point, which necessarily finds a neighbor.  Then pretend that you've got a little guy at that point, put his right hand on the wall, then have him find his way clockwise around the point.  When he gets back, he'll have found the rest.

What do I mean by find his way clockwise?  For example suppose that you go Down from the neighbor to get to his point.  Then your guy should be faced the first of Right, Up, and Left which he has a neighbor.  If he can go Right, he will, then he will try the directions Down, Right, Up, and Left.  (Just imagine trying to walk through the maze yourself with your right hand on the wall.)

This way lies insanity.

Here are two alternative data structures that are much easier to work with.

You can use a quadtree.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree for a description.  With this inserting a node is logarithmic in time.  Finding neighbors is also logarithmic.  And you're only using space for the data you have, so even if your graph is very spread out this is memory efficient.

Alternately you can create a class for a type of array that takes both positive and negative indices.  Then one that builds on that to be 2-d class that takes both positive and negative indices.  Under the hood that class would be implemented as a regular array and an offset.  So an array that can start at some number, positive or negative.  If ever you try to insert a piece of data that is before the offset, you create a new offset that is below that piece by a fixed fraction of the length of the array, create a new array, and copy data from the old to the new.  Now insert/finding neighbors are usually `O(1)` but it can be very wasteful of memory.

Comment: I like your answer as well...but unfortunately I could only pick one as the best....